# varnish vcl to strip query parameters but not all

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

In varnish vcl logic, Is there any way to strip all query parameters in a URL except few which affects the page behavior.

For example,

```
 www.xyz.com/search?city=sandiego&state=CA&type=xml&number=321&key=afdsf34345
```

Wanted to keep the "city" and "type" but whatever others to be stripped.

I tried with regsub, but it didnt work.

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
$ cat test.vtc 
varnishtest "Remove certain parameters."

server s1 {
  rxreq
  txresp -body "made it!"
} -start

varnish v1 -vcl {
  backend default {
    .host = "${s1_addr}";
    .port = "${s1_port}";
  }

  sub vcl_recv {
      if (req.url ~ "\?") {
          set req.http.X_City = regsub(req.url,  ".*[?&](city)=(\w+).*", "\1=\2");
          set req.http.X_Type = regsub(req.url,  ".*[?&](type)=(\w+).*", "\1=\2");
          set req.url = regsub(req.url,  "(.*)\?.*", "\1");
          set req.url = req.url + "?" + req.http.X_City + "&" + req.http.X_Type;
          unset req.http.X_City;
          unset req.http.X_Type;
      }
  }

  sub vcl_deliver {
      set resp.http.X_Test_Result = req.url;
  }
} -start

client c1 {
  txreq -url "/search?city=sandiego&state=CA&type=xml&number=321&key=afdsf34345"
  rxresp

  expect resp.http.X_Test_Result == "/search?city=sandiego&type=xml"
  expect resp.status == 200
  expect resp.body == "made it!"

} -run

varnish v1 -expect client_req == 1
```

Running that through `varnishtest` passes:

```
$ varnishtest test.vtc 
#     top  TEST test.vtc passed (1.341)
```